# Why does Load Balancer turn a 4XX error into 5XX

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

So we have been trying to get a few applications running on a GKE cluster with autopilot.

However when we went to test we get 5XX errors when we were expecting 4XX. This is even stranger because when we receive a 2XX response the message is received accordingly.

Upon reviewing application logs we see that the inteded output is the 4XX however, when the response is sent to the client, it is sent as a 5XX. What could be changing the response? Where does this response come from?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Unable to forward your request to a backend - Web Forwarder - Cloud Shell</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: monospace;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 1.5em;">Unable to forward your request to a backend</h1>
    <p>Couldn&#39;t connect to a server on port 8080</p>
</body>
```

The load balancers follow this template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
  namespace: namespace
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  selector:
    app: app-gateway
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http
```

And the ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
  namespace: namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.internal
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-gateway
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Upon request this is the architecture for the system. Names were omitted[image]

This is a very straightforward approach, just a few workloads behind a internal load balancer, connected to an on-prem Mongo and Rabbit.

**Edit** - Some more details

The way i'm doing is by setting up a port forward from my gcp console to the pod.

When I go to /swagger/index.html and try to test the API it returns 503 errors when a 4XX is expected. However a 2XX is sent sucessfully.
[image: Response using swagger]
When I port forward in my own console (using the same command as in GCP console) and do a `curl -X -I GET localhost:8080/swagger/index.html` I get the correct response.
[image]

Meaning it's likely something regarding the cloud shell itself.

Comment: Can you cross check your targetPort is same as containerPort?

Comment: Hi, can you share the following information below for further understanding.

1. What is your expected behavior. 
2. Is this for internal access or external access.
3. Diagram of your set up.
4. Documentation that you are following

Comment: @Sridhar Both targetPort and containerPort are set to 80.

Comment: @YvanG I expected the same status code from the application to be sent to the client. I don't understand why it's being transformed into a 5XX

Comment: @Eddoasso can you change `type: LoadBalancer` to `type: ClusterIP` in Service

Comment: @Sridhar sadly no, because of client specifically requested as type LoadBalancer.

And no, I'm not sure they are fully aware of what they are requesting. But they are paying for it

Comment: Do you have a vpn set up? Upon checking the yaml it shows that your load balancer is internal which does not have an external ip address. Just want to know how the on premise source accesses the GCP network.

I suggest performing a connectivity test to know if both traffic will go to the same route. Is there any reason why your client needs an internal load balancer?

Comment: @YvanG.   The client uses Partner Interconnect to link with their on prem datacenter. From there, it's a project that hosts a shared VPC and configures all connections to other projetcs. I apreciate all the help you gave. Sadly we have decided to take the aproach of "don't worry until it causes issues" and just go with the CURL requests to make sure everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

We need to know how your traffic routes using both sources when testing using curl. I suggest using the Connectivity Test. In this way we can identify if both devices (source) have the same route when reaching its destination.

To know more about my suggestion you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/concepts/overview#analyze-configurations). From the link you will see the information where traffic might go to a different path. From here we might see another useful information why we are having these kinds of error messages and will look at a different angle on how to resolve the issue.